# After removing Ubuntu Builder there is still folder in home directory. Why? How to remove it?

Tags: purge

I removed Ubuntu Builder using Synaptic with option Mark for Complete Removal. I thought that gonna delete folder (made by Ubuntu Builder) in home dir, but it's not.
AFAIK Mark for Complete Removal is same as Purging, and that should delete all files made by program. Am I wrong?
Is it safe to delete it with `sudo rm -r /home/ubuntu-builder` because it is in home dir?
And last question. Why is it made folder in /home instead in ~/ dir?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu builder creates it's own user account to build the new Ubuntu image in. The folder you're seeing is the home folder from this user.

My guess as to why it's still there is that Ubuntu Builder probably creates this user on runtime (when it's launched) and not when it's installed.

You can remove it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> to open a terminal, then entering this command:

```
sudo rm -r /home/ubuntu-builder
```